# React-router-dom nav links not rendering

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-router-dom

I'm trying to build a navigation with react-router-dom but Navlink or anything from react-router-dom won't render when I run build.

```
     My file webpack.config

` module.exports = {
        entry: ['./src/index.js'],
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            filename: 'bundle.js'

    },
    devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
          },
    `



     My navigation.js file
`import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';



    const Navbar  = () =>{

          return (

         <div><ul><li>
          <NavLink to "/work">Work</NavLink></li></ul></div>
          );
      }
      export default Navbar;`
```

Comment: Your syntax is not correct for `NavLink`- Refer to this [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/7m90pkm5k0?from-embed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have something inside your `<NavLink>` element.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md) where they provide the following example:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

<NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
```

Comment: The problem was I had react-router installed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we need to install the `react-router-dom`. Use the below command to install the `react-router-dom`,

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

Then import `Link` and use it like below,

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

<Link to="/about">About</NavLink>
```